# JsTrans Yii Configuration

Tags: yii2, yii-extensions, yii-components

I want to use JsTrans extension in my yii2 advanced project. https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/jstrans
But I have problem with the configuration. After I downloaded the extensions, I extract it in common/extensions folder with name "JsTrans". And then I add this code in my main config:

```
'components' => [
    ...
    'jsTrans' => array(
        // 'class'=>'ext.JsTrans.JsTrans', 
        'class' => 'common\extensions\JsTrans\JsTrans',
        'categories' => array('app'),
        'languages' => array('en', 'id'),
        // 'defaultLanguage' => 'en', // Optional
    )
],
```

But when I called this in view, I get error: **Getting unknown property: yii\web\Application::jstrans**
[My view code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozmtv.png)

I also tried call it using Yii::$app->jsTrans->init(); but I get another error: **Unable to find 'common\extensions\JsTrans\JsTrans' in file: D:\xampp\htdocs\my-project\common/extensions/JsTrans/JsTrans.php. Namespace missing?**

Comment: You need to change the namespace in `common/extensions/JsTrans/JsTrans.php`. Namespace should be `namespace common/extensions/JsTrans;`

Comment: That extension is for Yii 1.x not for Yii 2.

Comment: @MichalHynčica Oh, I think I'm careless about this. Do you know the similar extension for Yii2?

Comment: It looks like there is [w3lifer/yii2-i18n-js](https://github.com/w3lifer/yii2-i18n-js) that seems to be similar. But, I've never used it. Or you can use some independent JS internationalization library for example check https://openbase.com/categories/js/best-javascript-internationalization-libraries

Comment: @MichalHynčica Thank you. I've tried that yii-i18n-js extension. It works well and simple.